# Как сохранить результаты pdpbox.isolate() в dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

Я постраела pdp_isolate

```
pdp = pdp.pdp_isolate(
model=loaded_model, dataset=X, model_features=feature_names,   feature='col1'
)
fig, axes = pdp.pdp_plot(pdp, 'Results MODEL')
```

Результы полученного графика мне нужно сохранить в dataframe.
Я пробовала с помощью команды

```
pdp.count_data
```

Но тогда прогноз сохраняется для промежутка значений 'col1', а мне нужно для каждой точки num_grid_points сохранить прогноз.

Comment: вы хотите сохранить график (картинку) в DataFrame? PS а зачем?

Comment: @MaxU Да. Мне нужны отдельно значения осей X и Y для последующей визуализации.